# Script that benchmarks CPU performance giving a result that can be used to compare against other servers?

Tags: performance, shell, monitoring, benchmarking, cpu-usage

Any help with the below will be very much appreciated:

- This script should not overrun the box to the extent all the resources are used.
- As an example, the script could run an integer equation that works out response time as a measurement of performance.
- My theory is to attach it to a monitoring system to periodically run the test across multiple servers.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem - what are you _actually_ trying to accomplish? A CPU benchmark script isn't very meaningful for most 'real world' applications.

Comment: I have added a comment on your answer to attempt to clarify this.

Answer (score 5):

Performance testing isn't nearly as simplistic as that. All you test doing a particular operation is how fast a system completes that particular operation on that particular day.

CPUs are fast now, and they're rarely the bottleneck any more.

So this comes back to the question - what are you trying to accomplish? If you really want a relative measure of CPU speed, then you could try something like using the system utility `time`.

Something like:

`time ssh-keygen -b 8192 -f /tmp/test_ssh -N '' -q`

Following on from comments: This will prompt you to overwrite. You can always delete `/tmp/test_ssh`. (I wouldn't suggest using a variable filename, as that'll be erratic)

As an alternative - if it's installed - then I'd suggest using `openssl`.

E.g.

`time openssl genrsa 4096`

Time returns 3 numbers by default:

- 'real' - elapsed wallclock time.
- 'user' - cpu-seconds spent running the user elements of the task.
- 'sys' - cpu-seconds spent running system stuff.

For this task - I'm not entirely sure how the metrics pan out - I'm not 100% sure if VMware 'fakes' the CPU time in the virtualisation layer. Real and user should (for this operation) be pretty similar, normally.

I've just tested this on a few of my VMs, and have had a fairly pronounced amount of 'jitter' in the results. But then, this might be what you're actually testing for. Bear in mind though - CPU isn't the only contended resource on a VM. Memory/disk/network are also shared.

Comment: Well I have VMware guests in Hong Kong and London and I want to see if the VM is the issue as I have no access to the VM host. I see that both have the same Virtual specs but want to know if the performance differs drastically...
What does your ssh-keygen test do?

Comment: ssh-keygen generates a new rsa key-pair for ssh.  Which is a numerically intensive operation, so quite good for CPU comparisons.

Comment: I like where you are going with ssh-keygen but this test is something I want to run periodically on a box to monitor the result to spot spikes for example. It asks me to overwrite key file when ran a second time... Anything better along these lines, perhaps a maths equation?

Comment: There's not many equations that take more than a trivial amount of time for a modern CPU. Encryption algorithms (such as generating an RSA key) are probably the best example. ssh-keygen is almost certain to be installed. I'd suggest using openssl instead, but that's not necessarily present. (You can also remove the file, or write it to /dev/null instead!)

Comment: openssl is installed and I tried: time openssl genres 10000 and I can clearly see a mass difference. When running that command, I take it the output is immediately discarded and not saved to a file?
So I could have this run many times on multiple servers and record the real time field as my result?

Comment: OK. So openssl is a good bet. Adjust your key lengths so you get a 'few seconds' of runtime - too short and the overheads will mean you don't get a meaningful result.

Comment: It's generating prime numbers for encryption. That's an expensive task, which is part of what cryptography is based upon. It'll print the key to STDOUT, but you don't care so just discard it. Bear in mind that cpu time will increase exponentially with key length.

Comment: 'real' time isn't what you want to look at. 'user' time is the measure of CPU-seconds spent processing. (Real includes waiting for responses for IO)

Comment: The results are all over the place and sadly do not prove anything.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Generating an RSA key is pretty fundamentally the 'complex equation' you allude to in your original post. It's a numerically intensive operation. But why are you surprised at variable results? The whole point of VMs is that they're redistributing CPU time across a lot of instances.

Comment: Good point, let me investigate a bit further with it tomorrow. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `time openssl dhparam -out ~/dh4096.pem 4096` is it work as well?